# IPostBackEventHandler RaisePostBackEvent not triggered on asynchronous postback

Tags: asp.net, asynchronous, postback

I have designed a custom user control, basically a button, that implements the `IPostBackEventHandler` interface, and obviously defines the `RaisePostBackEvent(string eventArgument)` method, where I do some processing, basically I trigger other events.

By default, when clicked my control will execute `__doPostBack` its client id for a full page refresh, and of course RaisePostBackEvent is triggered.

However, I want to be able the use the control to refresh an update panel, so from client side I use the `__doPostBack` method with the ID of the update panel and an additional argument.

The problem is that `RaisePostBackEvent` is not triggered. I know i could look in `Page.Request.Params["__EVENTARGUMENT"]` and do whatever I need, but I would really like something as simple and elegant as `IPostBackEventHandler` so as to have all the logic in my control.

Long story short, how can I trigger `RaisePostBackEvent` in case I have an asynchronous postback? Or is there another interface that with similar functionality?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The thing is (if I understand your question correctly) that the control that calls the __doPostBack must implement IPostBackEventHandler interface. So, for example if I have this markup in a usercontrol (that implements the IPostBackEventHander):

```
<asp:Button runat="server"
     UseSubmitBehavior="false" ID="Button"
     Text="Update"
     OnClientClick="myfunction();"/>
```

The myfunction javascript must look like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function myfunction(param)   
    {
        __doPostBack("<%= this.UniqueID %>", "myargs");    
    }
</script>
```

Notice that I send this.UniqueID and not the Button.UniqueID because the button does not implement IPostBackEventHander but the usercontrol does.

Comment: The thing is that in the control I have an update panel and through an asynchronous postback I have to update just the content of the update panel so in my javascript function I say  `__doPostBack("updatePanelID", "myargs");` and the method `RaisePotsBackEvent` is never called, even though my control implements the `IPostBackEventHandler` interface.

Comment: But UpdatePanel does not implement IPostBackEventHandler, or am I missing something? So you can´t send the Id of the UpdatePanel as the first argument to __DoPostBack(...) you have to send the Id of your control and also the Unique (namingcontainer id) of that control.

Comment: plus 1 for using UniqueID. I was using ClientID which caused the RaisePostBackEvent to not fire.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and found this topic when i was looking for the solution. I found it so I will post it to help developers who could have the same issue.

Implement the IPostBackEventHandler interface in your UserControl :

```
Public Class UserControl_Rattachement
Inherits System.Web.UI.UserControl
Implements ICallbackEventHandler, IPostBackEventHandler
```

In the RaisePostBackEvent function, call the Update() method of your UpdatePanel :

```
Public Sub RaisePostBackEvent(eventArgument As String) Implements System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent
    // Code executed during the PostBack
    UpdatePanel1.Update()
End Sub
```

In the Page_Load method of your UserControl, define the PostBack as asynchronous :

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    ScriptManager.GetCurrent(Page).RegisterAsyncPostBackControl(Me)
End Sub
```

Now add the client script in the Render method :

```
Protected Overrides Sub Render(writer As System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter)
    MyBase.Render(writer)

    Dim postbackReference As String = Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(Me, Nothing, True)
    Dim postbackScript As String = String.Format("function updateRattachement() {{ {0}; }}", postbackReference)

    writer.WriteLine("<script type=""text/javascript"">")
    writer.WriteLine(postbackScript)
    writer.WriteLine("</script>")
End Sub
```

Then, call your client side function when you need it :

```
updateRattachement();
```

The PostBack will be asynchronous, and this will refresh the UpdatePanel you specified.

I hope this will help, and sorry for my english.

Answer (score 0):

```
this line is the key or the custom click event ignores updatepanel 
// ScriptManager.GetCurrent(Page).RegisterAsyncPostBackControl(this);
```

and note the IPostBackEventHandler part in page definition

```
in this example ordinary button and a custom click event div work together inside an update panel
```

public partial class tmp2 : System.Web.UI.Page, IPostBackEventHandler
{

`protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ScriptManager.GetCurrent(Page).RegisterAsyncPostBackControl(this);
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        div1.Attributes["onclick"] = ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(this, "ClickDiv");
    }
}
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Label1.Text += "1";
    UpdatePanel1.Update();
}
protected void Div1_Click()
{

    div1.InnerHtml += "b";
    UpdatePanel1.Update();

}



public void RaisePostBackEvent(string eventArgument)
{

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(eventArgument))
    {

        if (eventArgument == "ClickDiv")
        {

            Div1_Click();

        }

    }

}`

}